# How to add a nav item in wordpress only to a specific nav?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using this function to add an item to my primary nav when on mobile, but its adding the item to all my navs instead of only the primary nav. How or where can I add a parameter to specify which nav is getting the `add_last_nav_item()`

```
if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
   function add_last_nav_item($items) {
       return $items .= '<li class="text-center"><a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">TEST</a></li>';
   }
   add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_last_nav_item');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the `args` that are passed to the `wp_nav_menu_items` filter:

```
if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
   function add_last_nav_item($items, $args) {
       // Check the menu
       if ( $args->theme_location == 'your-menu-here' ) {
           return $items .= '<li class="text-center"><a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">TEST</a></li>';
        }
       
       // Returns the nav items if the condition isn't met.
       return $items;
   }
   add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_last_nav_item', 10, 2);
}
```

Here is the documentation on [`wp_nav_menu_items`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_items/) and here's the link to the documentation for the `$args` that are passed to the filter: [`wp_nav_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/)

As an aside, `wp_is_mobile()` isn't the best check if a user is on a mobile device. You might consider adding the menu item to the menu you want in the WP Admin area, and then just adding a `class` that hides it on desktop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did consider hiding the items I'm trying to add on desktop but they are Icons and have some interesting styles added to them so I figured this would be the best route. 

the $args addition broke my site and it fixed when I added the 10, 2 params to the add filter at the end (not sure what those are for) But now that the site is displaying correctly again the items I'm trying to add aren't appearing on any of the navs now.

Comment: The `10` and `2` are filter priority and number of arguments passed to the filter respectively. If you pass more than one argument to your function, you need those in the `add_filter`. Did you change the `your-menu-here` text? I don't know what the registered `theme_location` name you used.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I've been seeing '10, 2' as popular params and its been baffling me for a few days now lol. I did update 'your-menu-here' to my menu which is 'Primary'

Comment: It should be a lowercase value like `primary_nav` or `primary-menu` something like that. You can find out by doing a `echo '<pre>' . print_r( $args->theme_location, TRUE) . '</pre>';` right before the `if` statement. That should tell you all of your `theme_location` values.